# maven, execute console command

Tags: maven, exec

I have a pom with some plugins

I need to execute a console command just after a goal of one of plugins is executed  (this goal is not tied to any phase)

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the plugin http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/

tie it to the goal you want, and in it use the ant command exec.

ant commands can be found here: http://ant.apache.org/manual/

---

another option is also to use the plugin: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/